# repeated images outside

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web page, and I have the following CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('../images/numbers.png');
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I've set up a size for body (1024x900), but I see that page on browser I see numbers.png everywhere (my monitor resolution is bigger than that).

How can I set background image only inside body (defined as 1024x900)?
How can centre body in the middle of web browser?

By the way, image numbers.png is smaller that 1024x900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the body is everything you see in the page** "including white spaces on the left and right"

you need to have a container div like this

```
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    #container {
        background: url('../images/numbers.png');
        width: 1024px;
        height: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container" >
    <!-----page content goes here----->
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would give you +1, but you just repeated my answer 4 minutes later :)

Answer (score 3):

add `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

and for centering the body  using : `margin:0px auto;`

Comment: By the way, image numbers.png is smaller that 1024x900. Sorry, I forget it to say.

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
body {
background: url('../images/numbers.png') no-repeat center center;
display:block;
width: 1024px;
height: 900px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to create a page wrapper:

```
<body>
  <div id="page"></div>
</body>
```

Then adjust your styles:

```
#page {
  background: url('../images/numbers.png') no-repeat;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is a common approach and will save headaches later if you do things with *viewport*, like 100% height.